# Marionette.js ItemView - Put child view in region

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have the following `ItemView` template which is filled with customer data (firstName, lastName) and I want to add a `CollectionView` into the div `.addresses`.

Template

```
<script type="text/html" id="template-customer-details">
    <h4><%= firstName %> <%= lastName %></h4>
    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
    <h5>Addresses</h5>
    <div class="addresses">...</div>
</script>
```

Layout

```
Layout.Details = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#template-customer-details',

    regions: {
        addresses: ".addresses"
    },

    serializeData: function () {
        return this.model.attributes;
    },

    initialize: function () {

        this.addressList = new App.Models.AddressList();

        // Error!
        this.regions.addresses.show(this.addressList);

        this.bindTo(this, "render", this.$el.refresh, this.$el);
        this.model.bind("change", this.render.bind(this));
    }
});
```

I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object .addresses has no method 'show'."

Do I have to wait until the view is loaded?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you've got things a bit confused.  An `ItemView` doesn't do anything with a `regions` property (you may be thinking of the `Application` class), so when you try to call `this.regions.addresses.show` that's the same as calling `".addresses".show`.

I think you probably want to use a `CompositeView` in this case as it combines an `ItemView` (which you can use for your customer data) and a `CollectionView` which you can use for your AddressList.  You'll also need to define a separate `ItemView` for an address (as a `CollectionView` just creates an `ItemView` for each item in a collection).

Something a little like this (which I've not tested, so may not be entirely correct):

```
AddressView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#addressTemplate'
});

Layout.Details = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: '#template-customer-details',
    itemView: AddressView,
    itemViewContainer: '.addresses'
});

// Then create your view something like this:
new Layout.Details({
  model: new App.Models.CustomerDetails(),
  collection: new App.Models.AddressList()
});
```

I also don't think you need to specifically bind the change & render events like in your example as marionette will usually take care of that (the same with your implementation of serializeData, which looks like it's vaguely the same as the default implementation)

Comment: This looks good :) Can I also use the CompositeView if I want to display two collections below the customer data (one for addresses and one for contacts) or should I use a Layout then?

Comment: @Dennis - use at Layout for that

Comment: For the current version which is 3.0, the itemView and itemViewContainer in CompsoiteView, should be childView and childViewContainer. rename 'item' to 'child'. http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.7/marionette.compositeview.html#compositeviews-childview